# WrapText to specific characters

Tags: python

I have few columns(dynamic no. of columns) and i want to output only 3 columns from it.

**Requirements:**

1. If input column have empty string, remove that column.
2. Each output columns should not be more than 30 characters.
3. Word should not be broken over multiple columns.
4. If, in the list as output, there is no data to fit into 3 output columns, we can sit with what we have.
5. Ignore trailing and leading spaces in output columns.

For example, if input column-1 has 35 characters, 30 characters should be in output column-1(if no word is broken) and rest of the 5 characters should go into output column-2. So input column-2 data will go into output Column-3 (by obeying above requirements).

Another example could be, if we pass 10 input columns to the function with empty string in column-1, column-4 and column-7. Just remove them and start using only 7 columns instead.

I wrote below function which does the wrapping to 30 characters but it doesn't do work broken or not. Would some one help on this.

```
def wraptext(*cols):
    n = 30
    col_list = [*cols]
    suppressed_empty = [a for a in col_list if "" != a]
    correct_col_list3 = [x[i:i+n for x in suppressed_empty if len(suppressed_empty)>0 for i in range(0,len(x),n)[0:3]
    return correct_col_list3
```

**Examples:**

```py
wraptext("hello world hello world helloworld", "hello Country hello CountryhelloCountry")
# ["hello world hello world", "helloworld", "hello Country hello"]

wraptext("", "hello world hello world helloworld", "hello Country hello CountryhelloCountry","","hello python")
# ["hello world hello world", "helloworld", "hello Country hello"]

wraptext("", "hello world", "hello Country","","hello python")
# ["hello world", "hello country", "hello python"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.

```py
def wraptext(*cols):
    result=[]
    for col in cols:
        if col:
            if len(col)<=30:
                result.append(col)
            else:
                words=col.split(' ')
                sentence=[]
                for word in words:
                    if len(sentence)>0 and (len(word)+len(sentence[-1])+1)<=30:
                        sentence[-1]+=' '+word
                    elif len(word)<=30:
                        sentence.append(word)
                    else:
                        break
                result+=(sentence)
    return result[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```py
import textwrap

def wraptext(*cols):
    # Filter out the empty list
    filtered_cols = list(filter(None, cols))
    
    def wrap(l):
        """
        Recursively wrap up all
        the contents of the string
        """
        
        if not l:
            return []
        
        # pop the first element of the list
        s = l.pop(0)
        return textwrap.wrap(s, 30) + wrap(l)
        
    return wrap(filtered_cols)[:3]
    


l = wraptext("", "hello world hello world helloworld", "hello Country hello CountryhelloCountry","","hello python")
print(l)

l = wraptext("hello world hello world helloworld", "hello Country hello CountryhelloCountry")
print(l)

# ['hello world hello world', 'helloworld', 'hello Country hello']
# ['hello world hello world', 'helloworld', 'hello Country hello']
```

Let me know if this works. I've explained everything in the comments.